# Shiny Server drops off

Tags: r, server, shiny

I have a shiny server and actually I have been able to upload and use "online" some simple apps, and also the shiny and rmardown test works properly.
But then, when I try to use my own application (which works locally, on my computer), I get the following error message (I looked in log -> var/log/shiny-server):

```
 su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Loading required package: viridisLite
Loading required package: heatmaply

======================
Welcome to heatmaply version 0.14.1

Type citation('heatmaply') for how to cite the package.
Type ?heatmaply for the main documentation.

The github page is: https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/
Please submit your suggestions and bug-reports at: https://github.com/talgalili/heatmaply/issues
Or contact: <tal.galili@gmail.com>
======================


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43894

Execution halted
```

The session info:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0
```

I reinstaled both packages, and I also try to call them in R (sudo -i R to use R in console and then library(viridisLite) and library(heatmaply)) and they both works without problem.

When I try to use my App, server gets disconected and I have to restart it (My app starts to charge but when I reach to log issue, stops working)

Maybe the R version has to do with my issue, but I tried to change it unsuccesfully.

Best rewards,

Daniel.

Comment: The only error message you're seeing in the log is "Execution halted"? Is there any more to it?

Comment: I had voted to close this question, since according to your (deleted) answer, you solved it. But now that you've deleted your answer, I'm wondering - do you still have this problem? If you solved it yourself, please add an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry Frank! My problem is solved I have undeleted the answer, my fault.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have installated the last shiny-server version and also went to wired connection -> IPv4-settings and delete the additional DNS server. It works!